# Positioning a menu list underneath a textbox with CSS

Tags: css, menu, textbox

I'm struggling with CSS to get my search box and list to look like how I want it. I want the list to be attached to the bottom of the textbox and I have no idea how to do that. Here is a short of what I've got so far...

```
 <style>
ul.drop{display:inline-block;}
ul.drop, ul.drop li { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #ECF1F3; color: #28313F;  }

ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover { position: relative; z-index: 599; background: #1e7c9a;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<label for="someinput">Search Ingredients</label>
<input id="someinput">
<ul id="menu" class="drop" style="overflow:auto; max-height:200px;">
  <a href="#"><li>ingredient1</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>ingredient2</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>ingredient3</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>ingredient4</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>ingredient5</li></a>
</ul>
  <label for="qty"></label>
  <input type="text" size="5" name="qty" id="qty" />
  g
  <button type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Add">Add</button>
</body>
```

The list is currently showing to the right of the box, I would like it to be directly underneath the textbox. I was considering a container div for the list, but wasn't sure if that was necessary.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't have an `<a>` as a child of a `<ul>` or an `<ol>` only an `<li>` is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here both would involve changing you html to the following:

```
<div class="inputHolder">
    <label for="left someinput">Search Ingredients</label>
    <input id="someinput" /><br />
    <ul id="menu" class="drop" style="overflow:auto; max-height:200px;">
        <li><a href="#">ingredient1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ingredient2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ingredient3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ingredient4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ingredient5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="inputHolder">
  <label for="qty">g</label>
  <input type="text" size="5" name="qty" id="qty" />
  <button type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Add">Add</button>
</div>
```

Then if you want to have your list appear above any further content (ie content will be pushed down), you need the following extra styles:

```
.inputHolder {float:left; margin-right:10px;}
#menu {margin-left:7.5em}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FteVT/3/

If you want your list to appear on top of (overlapping) any further content, you can use these styles:

```
.inputHolder {float:left; margin-right:10px; position:relative;}
#menu {position:absolute; left:7.5em; top:1.5em;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FteVT/4/

Comment: That's exactly what I was after, thanks :)

I'm actually going to style the list as a popup search so that when something is typed into the box, the list automatically pops up and starts to show results.

Answer (score 0):

sorry this is'nt really an answer but you might be interested in jquery chosen component, which does the job : [jQuery Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: Oh that's really nice. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code in a fiddle, I get this:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lera/VG642/

With this CSS

```
ul.drop{display:inline-block;}
ul.drop, ul.drop li { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #ECF1F3;     color: #28313F;  }
ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover { position: relative; z-index: 599; background: #1e7c9a;}
```

The list is under the search box and its label, not to the right as you said.  I don't think I'm clear where you want it from your question.

Did you want the list indented?  Can you clarify a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

To start you have a href before li that needs to be moved inside of the li, also remove display: block-inline and leave block only, then add #someinput { display: block}

```
<label for="someinput">Search Ingredients</label>
 <input id="someinput">
   <ul id="menu" class="drop" style="overflow:auto; max-height:200px;">
     <li> <a href="#">ingredient1</a></li>
     <li> <a href="#">ingredient2</a></li>
     <li> <a href="#">ingredient3</a></li>
     <li> <a href="#">ingredient4</a></li>
     <li> <a href="#">ingredient5</a></li>
  </ul>
  <label for="qty"></label>
  <input type="text" size="5" name="qty" id="qty" />
   <button type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Add">Add</button>
```

CSS Portion

```
 ul.drop{display:block;}
 ul.drop, ul.drop li { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #ECF1F3; color: #28313F;  }

 ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover { display: block; position: relative; z-index: 599; background: #1e7c9a;}
 #someinput {
display:block;
```

}

See my jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/P7z7d/embedded/result/